# Сортировка массива по частоте и возрастанию (JS)

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Есть массив `[5,4,9,1,5,5,9,1,9,3,9]` нужно отсортировать его и получить вид `[9,9,9,9,5,5,5,1,1,3,4]` большее количество чисел идет спереди, а числа с меньшим количеством но с большим порядком идут по возрастанию в конце массива.

ну вот к примеру:

```js
var m = [1, 2, 2, 4, 10, 6, 8, 8, 9, 8];
var count = m.length - 1;

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
  for (var j = 0; j < count - i; j++)
    if (m[j] > m[j + 1]) {
      var max = m[j];
      m[j] = m[j + 1];
      m[j + 1] = max;
    }
document.write(m);
```

но тут одинаковые числа ставятся по возростанию. а что нужно сделать чтобы они выводились в первую очередь в массиве?

Comment: А проблема/вопрос в чем?

Comment: "нужно отсортировать его" - сортируйте

Comment: имеется ввиду как правильно сделать эту самую сортировку...

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: ну вот к примеру:
var m = [1, 2, 2, 4, 10, 6, 8, 8, 9, 8]; var count = m.length-1;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
     for (var j = 0; j < count-i; j++)
        if (m[j]> m[j+1]) {
           var max = m[j];
           m[j] = m[j+1];
           m[j+1] = max;
        }
document.write(m);
но тут одинаковые числа ставятся по возростанию. а что нужно сделать чтобы они выводились в первую очередь в массиве?

Comment: @Igor не, тут же надо сортировать не по самим числам, а по количеству вхождений чисел, так что алгоритм несколько сложнее.

Comment: @MaxKievSky проходите по массиву, подсчитываете количество вхождений каждого числа, сортируете полученные пары "число - количество" по убыванию количества, после чего преобразуете их в массив. Если при равном количестве вхождений двух чисел сначала нужно выводить меньшее из чисел, то не забываете это учесть либо при сортировке, либо при преобразовании в массив.

Comment: @MaxKievSky Вы прочитали статью по ссылке?

Comment: прочел, но особых намеков не увидел...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Записываем в объект число вхождений, потом вытаскиваем из него максимальные. А одинаковые выбираем по возрастанию. Number преобразует строки в числа, иначе сравнение получается некорректное ("10"<"4").

```js
var m = [1, 2, 2, 4, 10, 6, 8, 8, 9, 8];
var count = m.length;
//создаем вспомогательный массив mysort
//и в нем считаем сколько каждое число встречается в исходном массиве
//то есть в итоге получим mysort[1]=1, mysort[2]=2, mysort[4]=1, mysort[6]=1 и тд
var mysort = {};
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  var k=m[i];
  if (mysort[k] === undefined) {
mysort[k]=1;
  } else {
mysort[k]++;
  }
}

var n = [];
//cчитаем сколько значимых элементов в этом массиве
var count = 0;
for (var item in mysort) {count++;}

//перебираем массив столько раз сколько в нём элементов
for (var i2=0; i2<count; i2++) {
  var maxcount = 0;
  var digit = 0;
  //в цикле находим элемент с максимальным значением
  for (var item in mysort) {
if (Number(mysort[item]) > maxcount) {
  //в maxcount пишем текущее максимальное значение
  //в digit индекс элемента с этим значением
  digit = Number(item);
  maxcount = Number(mysort[item]);
} else {
  //если значения одинаковы то в приоритете элемент с меньшим индексом
  if (mysort[item] == maxcount) {
    if (Number(item) < Number(digit)) {
      digit = Number(item);
    }
  }
}
  }
  //после того как нашли нужный элемент
  //удаляем его из массива mysort
  //и записываем в массив n число digit столько раз сколько значение maxcount
  delete mysort[digit];
  for (var i = 0; i < maxcount; i++) {
n.push(digit);
  }
}
//в результате в n отсортированный массив
document.write(n);
```

Comment: а можешь объяснить (в комментариях) построчно или по циклам что - где происходит в твоем коде? заране СПС!

Comment: Дописал комментарии в код.

Answer (score 4):

Отсортировать по убыванию числа вхождений в массив, а при равенстве по возрастанию самого числа ([подробнее о сортировке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432370/178988)):

```js
var a = [1, 2, 2, 4, 10, 8, 6, 8, 9, 8, 6, 6]

var count = Object.create(null)

for (var q=0; q<a.length; ++q) {
  count[a[q]] = ~~count[a[q]] + 1
}

a.sort(function (x, y) {
  return count[y]-count[x] || x-y
})

console.log(a.join(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Отсортировать по убыванию числа вхождений в массив, а при равенстве по возрастанию индекса первого вхождения данного числа (массив восстанавливается при помощи [сортировки подсчётом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC)):

```js
var a = [1, 2, 2, 4, 10, 8, 6, 8, 9, 8, 6, 6]

var count = Object.create(null)

for (var q=0; q<a.length; ++q) {
  if (!count[a[q]]) {
    count[a[q]] = {i:q, n:1}
  } else {
    ++count[a[q]].n
  }
}

var order = Object.keys(count).sort(function (x, y) {
  return count[y].n - count[x].n || count[x].i - count[y].i
})

var res = []

for (var q=0; q<order.length; ++q) {
  for (var w=0; w<count[order[q]].n; ++w) {
    res.push(+order[q])
  }
}

console.log(res.join(' '))
```